# Use version number in file links in Sphinx

Tags: versioning, python-sphinx

In Sphinx, file links can be generated using the following syntax:

```
`name_of_file.js <some/location/name_of_file.js>`_
```

In the conf.py file, a `version` variable is defined that we can use in the .rst files like such:

```
|version|
```

Including the version into the file link using that syntax is not allowed:

```
`name_of_file.|version|.min.js <some/location/name_of_file.|version|.min.js>`_
```

So, how can I generate links to files named something like `name_of_file.<version_num>.min.js` and use the version number from conf.py?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a need for something similar and after much experimentation I have a workaround for this. Be warned, this is a crummy solution but it works.

**The short answer:**

You need to split the parts of the link to left and right of |version| and use raw html along with the `|version|`. Your .rst will look like this:

```
Example of a link with version in it |link-pre|\ |version|\ |link-post|

.. |link-pre| raw:: html

    <a href="some/location/name_of_file.

.. |link-post| raw:: html

    .min.js">name_of_file.min.js</a>
```

**The long answer**

There are a couple of hurdles we need to overcome:

Problem 1: 
Now, `|version|` is essentially a [substitution definition](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions). When you use a [substitution reference](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-references) in your document, it has to lead with a `space` like so `|version|`.

So even in a regular rsT sentence, which is not a link, you can't do `name_of_file.|version|.min.js`. You will need to do `name_of_file.\ |version|.min.js`, i.e, escape the `space` with a `\`

Problem 2: Nested inline markup is not supported in reST: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible

So you can't make a substitution, `|version|`, within a link `` \`name_of_file.|version|.min.js`\ ``. This is why we have to use raw-html and break it into parts, and we create 2 more substitution definitions `|link-pre|` and `|link-post|`, which will be replaced with their raw-html in the generated output.

I tried using inline `:raw-html:` [role](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw) but that did not help, so unfortunately the solution turned out to be verbose.

Comment: **Good news**

This works great in HTML

**Bad news**

It doesn't render as a hyperlink in PDF (via latexpdf). But at least it doesn't error out.

Answer (score 0):

The above doesn't work for PDF's as mentioned, a workaround for PDF's would be to lean in on the power of LaTeX without too much complexity.

In your `config.py`, we'll add a LaTeX function called `\versionLink`:

```py
__version__ = 0.1 # Just an example of how to get it into the latex string dynamically
latex_prlog = rf"""
\newcommand{{\versionLink}}{{domain.local/name_of_file.{__version__}.min.js}}
"""
```

All it will do, is output a link text that you want to show.

We need to escape `{` and `}` by doing `{{` and `}}` if we're using formatted strings, since LaTeX uses those for function definitions. *(If you don't need string formatting, just don't use `f""` and omit the double `{{ }}` and use `{ }` instead.)*

Then, in our documentation, we can generate links with:

```markdown
.. This is needed, to be able to do inline latex:
.. role:: raw-latex(raw)
   :format: latex

Here's a version link :raw-latex:`\url{https://\versionLink}`.
It will have the same color throughout.
```

The `..role:: raw-latex(raw)` just enables you to do inline LaTeX. And with that you can do `\url{https://\versionLink}` inline in your text.
Tested with `make latexpdf`.